# java ball to line collision not working

Tags: java

I'm working on my game project prototype in Java and I have problem with the line "collision". I've tried many different ways to get it to work. Can anyone try to help me? I just ran out of ideas, checked some sites like Mathworld but when I try to redo this math into code it's not really working.

```
class Ball {

    int x, y, radius, dx, dy;
    Color BallColor;

    public Ball(int x, int y, int radius, int dx, int dy, Color bColor) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.radius = radius;
        this.dx = dx;
        this.dy = dy;
        BallColor = bColor;
    }
}

public class ball_1 extends Applet implements Runnable, MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {

    Ball ball1, ball2;
    int x1, x2, y1, y2,r1;
    int a, b;
    String msg = "";
    double c,d,e;


    @Override
    public void init() {
        this.setSize(800, 800);
        ball1 = new Ball(400, 70, 20, 4, 1, Color.green);
        ball2 = new Ball(40, 70, 20, 4, 1, Color.black);
        Thread t = new Thread(this);
        t.start();
        addMouseListener(this);
        addMouseMotionListener(this);
        Point p1 = new Point(x1,y1);
        Point p2 = new Point(x2,y2);
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(ball1.BallColor);
        g.fillOval(ball1.x, ball1.y, ball1.radius, ball1.radius);
        g.setColor(ball2.BallColor);
        g.fillOval(ball2.x, ball2.y, ball2.radius, ball2.radius);
        g.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
        g.drawString(msg, 80, 80);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        boolean run = true;
        while (run) {
            try {

                displacementOperation(ball2);
                lineCollision(ball1);
                ballCollision(ball1);
                ballCollision(ball2);
                Thread.sleep(40);
                repaint();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            if (ball1.x >= 780 || ball1.y <= 0) {
                run = false;
                msg = "game over";
            }
            if (ball1.y >= 780 || ball1.x <= 0) {
                run = false;
                msg = "game over";
            }
        }
    }

    public void displacementOperation(Ball ball) {
        if (ball.y >= 780 || ball.y <= 0) {
            ball.dy = -ball.dy;
        }
        if (ball.x >= 780 || ball.x <= 0) {
            ball.dx = -ball.dx;
        }
        ball.y = ball.y - ball.dy;
        ball.x = ball.x - ball.dx;

    }

    public void lineCollision(Ball ball) {
        d = ((y2-y1)*(ball.radius) -(x2-x1)*(ball.radius) +x2*y1 -y2*x1)/((y2-y1)*(y2-y1))/2 + ((x2-x1)*(x2-x1))/2 ;
        if (ball.radius <= d){
            ball.dy = -ball.dy;
            ball.dx = -ball.dx;

        }

        ball.y = ball.y - ball.dy;
        ball.x = ball.x - ball.dx;


    }

    public void ballCollision(Ball ball) {
        a = (ball2.y - ball1.y) * (ball2.y - ball1.y) + (ball2.x - ball1.x) * (ball2.x - ball1.x);
        b = ((ball1.radius + 10) + (ball2.radius + 10)) / 2 * ((ball1.radius + 10) + (ball2.radius + 10)) / 2;
        if (a <= b) {
            ball.dy = -ball.dy;
            ball.dx = -ball.dx;

        }

        ball.y = ball.y - ball.dy;
        ball.x = ball.x - ball.dx;

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        x1 = e.getX();
        y1 = e.getY();
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

        x2 = e.getX();
        y2 = e.getY();
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        x2 = e.getX();
        y2 = e.getY();
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
    }
```

Comment: What is wrong with the code? What specifically does not work? What debugger are you using to see the values as they are calculated?

Comment: sorry for not beeing clear as i shoud . this code mostly like dont detect line in any point and if it mostly cause ball to stuck in place . its running and dont showing any errors i use NetBeans. Wrong is math in lineCollision part i belive is thing that couses it .And for last question im rather newbie in codeing so i dont have answer for your question here.

Comment: A debugger allows you to step through a program and see values calculated. https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/debug-visual.html That is what you need to see in order to understand why the line collision is not calculated correctly.

Comment: Just used debugger but its not showing me any values to be honest thats mean i done something wrong. The thing idk is how to setup in code is "Hey ball you touched line change movement direction" .And now i know i shoud comment each important thing before to make its clearer before putting in with question.

Comment: Found this http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circle-LineIntersection.html and i trying to redo my code to if one intersection bounce off line. But still not sure how to do this in code .

Comment: You should try the math in an Unit Test. Creating a ball and a line and just verifying if the collision is working for different positions of the ball and the line.

Comment: @morcha - Do you already understand the math of determining when an intersection is made, or is that the goal of this effort? Are you trying to do this without understanding the intersection math?

Comment: i know how its work on paper but i have problems to put in into code or i only think i know and lack of knowledge in both determining and codeing .@lit